# Select longest match

Tags: javascript

I have an array of names;

```
["Agent 1", "Agent 12", "Agent 2"]
```

I will receive a string (that may or may not contain one of the words in the array) that I need to search through and, if a match is found, return the array value.

For example, I may receive the string.

```
I spoke to Agent 1 the other day.
```

I use the following algorithm to search for any matches.

```
for (var i in agent_names) {
    var name = agent_names[i];

    if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return agent_names[i];
    }
}

return null;
```

This works fine for `Agent 1`. However if the same message said;

```
I spoke to Agent 12 the other day.
```

The algorithm will still match `Agent 1` as it is part of the string.

Essentially, I am looking for a best fit search rather than first fit. `indexOf` does not work in this instance.

The only way I can think of doing this is brute forcing it by letter and storing the longest match. But this seems inefficient?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a fuzzy search to determine the best match for your string. There are a lot of answers and debates on methodologies, but why not settle on a small 8kb library that does this for you? https://github.com/Glench/fuzzyset.js

Comment: Also be sure to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea and avoid using `for...in` for array iteration

Comment: A fuzzy search is a step too far. The longest match will always be preferred. And i'll check out that `for...in` thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your array of words before matching loop begins :

```
agent_names = agent_names.sort(function(i,j){return i.length < j.length})
for (var i in agent_names) {
    var name = agent_names[i];

    if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return agent_names[i];
    }
}

return null;
```

Comment: The code you posted has syntax error. I also recommend to not use `for...in` to iterate over an array.

Comment: Yep this works! Although it's `agent_names.sort` not `=`. Simple and effective.

Comment: I have corrected the agent_names.sort bug in the code as well. Note tried running it but I hope it can clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Order the list of strings by length descending.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
reg = '\\b(' + name.toLowerCase() + ')\\b'; 
if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf(reg) !== -1) {
    return agent_names[i];
}
```

This will ensure that you are looking for the search term within `word boundaries` so you won't accidentally match 'Agent 13' or 'Agent 12' when looking for 'Agent 1'

Answer (score 0):

`.match(/\d+/)` will return number from string .So store number array `agent_names` and get the greatest number by `Math.max`.Then you can replace your string by `replace`.

```
var name_arr = [];
for (var i in agent_names) {        
    name_arr.push(agent_names[i].match(/\d+/));//store number array
}
replace_text = Math.max.apply(Math,name_arr);//get greatest number
msg = msg.replace("1",replace_text); //replace with greatest number
console.log(msg);
```